# Better options than vlookup in JAVA

Tags: java, vlookup

I'm working on program which involves comparing two excel sheets. I kind of succeeded using the excel vlookup simply applying a column.

I think it is kind of slow when the sheets get bigger so i was wondering if there is any other way i could speed up this process. I mean any other JAVA implementation i could look into which would really help me?

Comment: you could write your own comparing program using JXL/apache POI... In case you wanna compare only specific columns/rows. Its not that difficult..

Comment: Java application would be far more tedious..also you will require a lot of heap space to load large excel files

Comment: There ARE ways of doing this, but I seriously believe you won't be able to make any Java-based method outperform the VLOOKUP function.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this sort of thing in java regarding office 2007+ excel files is

- Open a ZipInputStream on the excel file
- Read the SheetN.XML entry(ies) using an XML parser. N is the number of the sheet (s) you are trying to read in
- Read in the shared strings file using an xml parser and build a lookup table

From there you can implement whatever algorithm you need to. Check out [this spreadsheetxml walkthrough] (http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/introduction-to-spreadsheetml.aspx) for information on excel's file structure.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into all your options and in the meantime time i was actually doing vlookup with the code and i get this error at this point

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into all your options and in the meantime time i was actually doing vlookup with the code and i get this error at this point `wb=new XSSFWorkbook(file);`. The error is "org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions". I looked into other posts but nothing makes sense to me. The xlxs file i'm trying read in the code  is protected by "SoftCamp Document Security" application. Looks like it does some kind of encryption to the file. Any ideas to read an encrypted files