# Read from 1 excel and write those values in another excel using vlookups in java

Tags: java, excel

I am having an excel document with names populated. I want to read the characteristics of the names from multiple other documents using vlookup. I am using java poi(just started, so open to look at other solutions). I also need to do some calculations on some of the populated columns.

So far, I am able to read an excel file. Any other pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Update: More information

I have 2 files,

File 1 columns - Name, detail1,detail2
File 2 columns - Name, detail3,detail4 & so on

So I need to read both the files and copy the File 2 columns in File1 using vlookups. I need to automate this using java.

I have the code to read and write the files, so I just need to implement the vlookups.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838937/better-options-than-vlookup-in-java). There's some good information to get you started. Also, if this is entirely in Excel, is there any reason not to do it in VBA?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Other than me being comfortable in Java(Have not used VBA at all), there is no other reason.

Also I looked at the links and others, but I could not find anything related with doing VLOOKUPs. Am I missing something obvious?

Appreciate your help. Thanks.